# In web3.js is the .deployed function deprecated?

Tags: solidity, truffle

I was following a tutorial where i found that we can create an instance without passing the address of the contract to create the instance. Like this:

```
Voting.deployed().then(function(contractInstance) {
  contractInstance.voteForCandidate(candidateName, {gas: 140000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}).then(function() {
    let div_id = candidates[candidateName];
    return contractInstance.totalVotesFor.call(candidateName).then(function(v) {
      $("#" + div_id).html(v.toString());
      $("#msg").html("");
    });
```

I checked the web3.js documentation but couldn't find anything. Is this function deprecated?
Is there any other way of creating an instance of a contract without passing the address -I am using truffle and testrpc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the deployed function you're calling is part of Truffle, not `web3.js`.

As to how to deploy a contract via `web3.js`, here's an example snippet of code that I got from the "details" screen in Remix:

```
var testContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"n","type":"uint256"}],"name":"test","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"}]);
var test = testContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '0x6060604052341561000f57600080fd5b60ae8061001d6000396000f300606060405260043610603f576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff16806329e99f07146044575b600080fd5b3415604e57600080fd5b606260048080359060200190919050506078565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b60008190509190505600a165627a7a72305820ad206bc8d103ee40219f8a9e55fd456bcda22c986b40a97ae5eedbaa6dc791f90029', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```